# В виждетах QLineEdit, QTableWidget PyQt5, очень неудобно отображаются пути к файлам, не видно название самого файла

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2, qlineedit

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в виждетах QLineEdit, QTableWidget  (PyQt5), при отображении в них путей к файлам, не видно название самого файла, так как текст отображается начиная с левого края.
Единственный выход - это растянуть виджет, чтоб поместилась вся строка, но мне это не подходит.
Команды выравнивания текста так же не помогают в данном случае.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы было видно начало и конец строки одновременно, или только конец строки?

Comment: Конец строки, т.к. нужно видеть имя файла. Команда  line.end(False) из ответа помогла. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо после заполнения передвинуть курсор в конец поля при помощи метода QLineEdit.end():

```
line = QLineEdit()
line.setText("...")

line.end(False) # если True, то текст выделится
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @Helg1980  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour